# how do i fetch derived/calculated column from database view or Procedure in Spring Boot using JPA/Hibernate and use it along with predefined columns?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a project as am learning Spring Boot with JPA,Hibernate with Mustache as for templates. i managed to create a view with one calculated column which calculates an remaining days from issueDate and expiryDate. the view works fine and i am able to display all columns except the calculated column. I need help figuring out how to do that

My Entity Class

```
package com.demgo.demgoerp.model;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Formula;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class DocumentStorage
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
//    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long documentID;
    private String documentTitle;
    private String documentLocation;
    private String uploadDate;
    private String issueDate;
    private String expiryDate;



     @Formula(value = "select datediff(expiry_date,issue_date) as days_remaining from document_storage")
    private String  daysRemaining;

    public DocumentStorage()
    {
        super();
    }

    public DocumentStorage(String documentTitle, String documentLocation, String uploadDate, String issueDate, String expiryDate)
    {
        super();
        this.documentTitle = documentTitle;
        this.documentLocation = documentLocation;
        this.uploadDate = uploadDate;
        this.issueDate = issueDate;
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }


    public Long getDocumentID()
    {
        return documentID;
    }

    public void setDocumentID(Long documentID)
    {
        this.documentID = documentID;
    }

    public String getDocumentTitle()
    {
        return documentTitle;
    }

    public void setDocumentTitle(String documentTitle)
    {
        this.documentTitle = documentTitle;
    }

    public String getDocumentLocation()
    {
        return documentLocation;
    }

    public void setDocumentLocation(String documentLocation)
    {
        this.documentLocation = documentLocation;
    }

    public String getUploadDate()
    {
        return uploadDate;
    }

    public void setUploadDate(String uploadDate)
    {
        this.uploadDate = uploadDate;
    }

    public String getIssueDate()
    {
        return issueDate;
    }

    public void setIssueDate(String issueDate)
    {
        this.issueDate = issueDate;
    }

    public String getExpiryDate()
    {
        return expiryDate;
    }

    public void setExpiryDate(String expiryDate)
    {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }
}
```

my Repo

```
package com.demgo.demgoerp.dao;

import com.demgo.demgoerp.model.DocumentStorage;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface DocumentRepo extends JpaRepository<DocumentStorage, Long>
{

    @Query(value = "select * from ShowAllDocuments", nativeQuery = true)
    List<DocumentStorage> findAllDocuments();

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from document_storage")
    public List<DocumentStorage> getAllDocs();


}
```

My Database VIEW

```
create view  ShowAllDocuments
as

SELECT 
documentid,
document_location,
document_title,
upload_date,
issue_date,
expiry_date,
datediff(expiry_date,issue_date) as days_remaining
FROM document_storage;
```

My Controller:

```
package com.demgo.demgoerp.controller;

import com.demgo.demgoerp.dao.DocumentRepo;
import com.demgo.demgoerp.dao.MainRepo;
import com.demgo.demgoerp.model.DocumentStorage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

@Controller
public class OperationsController
{
    @Autowired
    private MainRepo mainRepo;
    @Autowired
    private DocumentRepo documentRepo;

    @GetMapping("/Operations")
    public String operationMain(Model model)
    {

        model.addAttribute("title", "Operations Main Page");
        System.out.println("Operations Main Page Accessed");
        return "Operations/OperationsMainPage";
    }

    @GetMapping("/Operations/Registration-Documents")
    public String registrationDocuments(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Operations: Registration Documents  ");
        model.addAttribute("documents", this.documentRepo.findAllDocuments());
        System.out.println(this.documentRepo.findAllDocuments());

        System.out.println("Operations: Registration Documents");
        return "Operations/registration-documents";

    }

    @GetMapping("/Operations/Add-Document")
    public String addDocument(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Operations: Add-Document");
        System.out.println("Operations: Add Document");
        return "Operations/AddDocument";
    }

    @PostMapping("/Operations/SaveDocument")
    public String saveDocument(DocumentStorage documentStorage, BindingResult result, Model model, @RequestParam(
            "documentLocation1") MultipartFile file)
    {
        System.out.println("FILE :" + file.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println(documentStorage.getDocumentLocation());
        if (result.hasErrors())
        {
            model.addAttribute("title", "Operations: Add-Document");
            model.addAttribute("Error", "Error Has Occurred");
            System.out.println("Error Has occurred");
            System.out.println(result.getAllErrors());
            return "Operations/AddDocument";
        }
        this.documentRepo.save(documentStorage);
        String UPLOAD_FOLDER = "C://users//Bob2609//Pictures//";
        if (file.isEmpty())
        {
            model.addAttribute("title", "Operations: Add-Document");
            model.addAttribute("Error", "No File Found ");

            return "Operations/AddDocument";
        }

        try
        {
//            read and write file to selected location
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get(UPLOAD_FOLDER+file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path,bytes);


        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        model.addAttribute("title", "Operations: Add-Document");

        return "Operations/AddDocument";

    }




}
```

I want to be able to list that days_remaining column along with the rest of the columns on my mustache view.

StackTrace :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-04-20 23:48:55.818  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] com.demgo.demgoerp.DemgoErpApplication   : Starting DemgoErpApplication on BOB2609WIN10ENT with PID 22204 (C:\Users\Bob2609\IdeaProjects\demgo-erp\target\classes started by Bob2609 in C:\Users\Bob2609\IdeaProjects\demgo-erp)
2020-04-20 23:48:55.821  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] com.demgo.demgoerp.DemgoErpApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-20 23:48:55.888  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\Bob2609\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/Bob2609/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/Bob2609/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/Bob2609/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/C:/Users/Bob2609/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/Bob2609/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/C:/Users/Bob2609/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
2020-04-20 23:48:55.888  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-04-20 23:48:55.888  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-04-20 23:48:56.728  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-04-20 23:48:56.797  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 62ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-04-20 23:48:57.345  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8092 (http)
2020-04-20 23:48:57.351  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-04-20 23:48:57.351  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-04-20 23:48:57.463  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-04-20 23:48:57.463  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1574 ms
2020-04-20 23:48:57.580  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-04-20 23:48:57.630  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-04-20 23:48:57.717  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-04-20 23:48:57.785  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-04-20 23:48:57.896  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-04-20 23:48:57.910  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
2020-04-20 23:48:58.498  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-04-20 23:48:58.505  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-04-20 23:48:58.530  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-04-20 23:48:58.813  WARN 22204 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-04-20 23:48:58.921  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-20 23:48:58.986  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2020-04-20 23:48:59.570  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8092 (http) with context path ''
2020-04-20 23:48:59.573  INFO 22204 --- [  restartedMain] com.demgo.demgoerp.DemgoErpApplication   : Started DemgoErpApplication in 4.103 seconds (JVM running for 5.537)
2020-04-20 23:49:12.309  INFO 22204 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-20 23:49:12.309  INFO 22204 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-20 23:49:12.315  INFO 22204 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 6 ms
Index Page Accessed
Operations Main Page Accessed
Hibernate: select * from ShowAllDocuments
2020-04-20 23:49:14.155 ERROR 22204 --- [nio-8092-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1241) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1235) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:374) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:343) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:277) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.result.DefaultColumnDefinition.findColumn(DefaultColumnDefinition.java:182) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:545) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:852) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getString(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3068) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1866) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1794) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1767) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1615) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:745) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1008) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2131) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1530) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.findAllDocuments(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.demgo.demgoerp.controller.OperationsController.registrationDocuments(OperationsController.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
```

@Jens Schauder per your previous comments will this do?
I can share the project files if that would help.

Comment: I'm confused you use the `@Formula` annotation, but also a view. You can just remove the view and use `findAll` to get all entities. I'd might have to wrap the formular in parenthesis though.

Comment: my aim is to use the view from the database, and it has a calculate column  
this one ```datediff(expiry_date,issue_date) as days_remaining``` when i call the view i can display all the original columns, except when i try to display the calculated column i get errors. i will post the error here in a moment

Comment: I have no way of referencing it here

 ```<tbody>
            {{#documents}}
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bolder">{{documentID}}</td>
                    <td><a class="my-link" onclick="testScript('{{documentLocation}}')">{{documentLocation}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{documentTitle}}</td>
                    <td>{{expiryDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{issueDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{uploadDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{daysRemaining}}</td>
                </tr>
            {{/documents}}
            </tbody> ```

Comment: after removing ```@Formula``` when i use ```{{daysRemaining}}``` or ```{{days_remaining}}```  i get this 
```No method or field with name 'daysRemaining' on line 32
com.samskivert.mustache.MustacheException$Context: No method or field with name 'daysRemaining' on line 32```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should EITHER use `@Formula` or a database view.

Since you made it clear that you prefer the view you should:

1. Map your entity to your view:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "ShowAllDocuments")
   public class DocumentStorage { 
       //...
   ```
2. Make sure JPA does not try to write the column, but only read it.

   ```
   @Column(updatable=false, insertable=false)
   private String  daysRemaining;
   ```

Comment: so just to understand i create a new Entity annotation to reference the view ?
it will be a different class right ?

Comment: this solution you provided works perfectly
```@Entity
@Table(name = "showAllDocuments")
public class DocumentStorage{@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private Long documentID;
    private String documentTitle;
    private String documentLocation;
    private String uploadDate;
    private String issueDate;
    private String expiryDate;
    @Column(updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private String  daysRemaining;
// ...```

Comment: if it were a Stored procedure being called instead of view what can be done differently ?

Comment: Okay i run into a little snag here
after mapping the Entity to my View when i run the code, it created a new table and called it show_all_documents, so now when i insert data it goes to this new Table.
i want to maintain my Table and view separately.

Comment: Regarding table creation: that won't work with views, turn it of and create your tables yourself. At the latest when you go to production you wan't to do that anyway. Checkout liquibase and flyway.

Comment: Regarding stored procedures: If you can hide it behind a view that would still work. If not `@Formula` is still an option.